# RandomForestClassifier takes less time to train when in Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am experiencing strange behavior in Scikit-learn.

When I train a RandomForestClassifier standalone (not in a pipeline), the model takes 280 seconds to train, while the training process only takes 18 seconds in a pipeline.

Am I doing something wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Your first cell calls `fit` _and_ `cross_val_score`. It should take at least 1+5 times as long, and perhaps quite a bit of the excess is from the overhead of `cross_val_score`?  Time just the `fit`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

In 1st block, you have 6 lines of code. You are importing libraries, fitting your model, getting scores, and doing everything for the first time. Whereas in 2nd block you are importing the libraries like Scikit-learn which is already imported, so it won't take time. And, in 3rd block there is just one line of code. Another reason is that, In 1st block, you are getting some kind of warning which might be affecting the speed of running the code.